# Waiting for asynchronous threads in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to wait for asynchronous threads in objective-c without blocking the UI thread (it is an app).

I have the following code:

```
-(void)MainUIThread
{
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
            //wait here without blocking
        });
    }];
}
```

In C# I would use async and await, can I easily achieve this in objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

```
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
     [self exportDidFinish:exporter]; // Its non blocking process
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Update your UI.
    });
}];
```

Try above snippet.

You calling  [self exportDidFinish:exporter] method on main thread that why it block your UI. I suppose exportDidFinish method have just a business logic then post that logic calculation in background thread using `dispatch_get_global_queue` then get it back on main thread using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my example to include the main thread. What do you mean by update your UI? My UI is the ios app which  seems to just run automatically.

Comment: @Jamesla you need to go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that you should wait for an asynchronous operation to finish? That's the whole point of asynchronous operation, you don't wait for it!

You called exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler and gave it a block. I don't know that method, but I assume it will do things asynchronously, and when it is finished it will call the block that you give it. The call to exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler will return very quickly, as soon as the method has set up its asynchronous operation.

That block dispatches another block calling "exportDidFinish:exporter" on the main thread, then it returns (with no reason to wait), then all the asynchronous code in exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler is finished.

All we have now is one block dispatched to the main queue. As soon as the run loop is idle, that block is executed on the main thread. The commented line that you added "// Wait here" is pointless. exportDidFinish:exporter will be called on the main thread when it's time to be called, and then we are done.